# Neural network receptive field visualization in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network, visualization, data-visualization

I have a neural network with 300 hidden layers that I want to visualize(all together).

What is the best way to do it in python?

I have already tried it using `subplot` but the receptive fields are too far from each other and I can barely see them.

**Edit:**

So on the output i just have 28*28 
weights(images) that I want to visualize.

This is my current code:

```
# Plot receptive fields
f, axarr = pyplot.subplots(30, 10)


for weight_numb in xrange(300):
    currnt_sub_handler = axarr[weight_numb / 10, weight_numb % 10]
    weight = main.model_params[:, weight_numb].reshape(28, 28)
    currnt_sub_handler.axis('off')
    currnt_sub_handler.imshow(weight)

pyplot.show()
```

So, to rephrase the question:

1. How do I make the images to be as close as possible to each other?
2. What colormap I have to use?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of visualization you want? Usually the best way is to work within whatever framework you are using to do the training / feature extraction.

Comment: @mprat I have 28*28 images in the amount of 300. I just want a nice way to put them in one image, so that people can clearly see each of them.

Comment: So your question is really how to draw 300 images next to each other?

Comment: @mprat, basically yes. I want to put them as close as possible. But I also guess that there are some colormaps that suit this task really well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make one large image (matrix) that is, say, (10x28)x(30x28), and you put each of your 28x28 filters into a piece of this matrix, then plot the entire image at once. Kind of like this:

```
# assuming your filters are stored in a list called all_filters
all_filter_image = zeros(10*28, 30*28)
for filter_num in range(300):
    # calculate start_x and start_y based on the size of your "large filter" 
    # and the filter index
    all_filter_image[start_x:start_x + 28, start_y: start_y + 28] = all_filters[filter_num]
```

This way you don't have to deal with subplots.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that I came up with. Thanks @mprat for the help.

I found out that `spectral` colormap is the best for this kind of tasks and
I also added border that you can specify.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

border = 2
images_amount = 300
row_amount = 10
col_amount = 30
image_height = 28
image_width = 28


all_filter_image = np.zeros((row_amount*image_height + border*row_amount,
                             col_amount*image_width + border*col_amount))


for filter_num in range(images_amount):
    start_row = image_height*(filter_num / col_amount) +\
                (filter_num / col_amount + 1)*border

    end_row = start_row + image_height

    start_col = image_width*(filter_num % col_amount) +\
                (filter_num % col_amount + 1)*border

    end_col = start_col + image_width

    all_filter_image[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col] = \
        all_filters[filter_num]

    print start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col


pyplot.imshow(all_filter_image)
pyplot.axis('off')
pyplot.set_cmap('spectral')
pyplot.colorbar()
pyplot.savefig('repflds1.png')
```

These are some examples of usage:

Not so well trained network:
[image]

Really good trained network:
[image]

As you can see the borders make it really easy to distinguish one filter(weight) from another.